# New to tor, is not working :(

Tags: configuration, help, connection

I downloaded tor which ran but was "unable to connect" when I tried to access any sites. I uninstalled it and reinstalled but now it is just displaying:

"Unable to connect to listener port"

```
8/30/19, 11:33:09.876 [WARN] You specified a public address '103.36.122.33:8080' for SocksPort. Other people on the Internet might find your computer and use it as an open proxy. Please don't allow this unless you have a good reason. 
8/30/19, 11:33:09.876 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/30/19, 11:33:09.876 [WARN] You specified a public address '103.36.122.33:8080' for SocksPort. Other people on the Internet might find your computer and use it as an open proxy. Please don't allow this unless you have a good reason. 
8/30/19, 11:33:09.876 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 103.36.122.33:8080 
8/30/19, 11:33:09.876 [WARN] Could not bind to 103.36.122.33:8080: Can't assign requested address 
8/30/19, 11:33:09.876 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

Please let me know how i can fix it! I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling over it again but it doesn't work. I am using admin account on mac.

Comment: This sounds very strange. Did you install Tor Browser from https://www.torproject.org/download/? If so, did you change any settings after installing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's working now, but I did it a time ago, in mac first, you need to have `brew` you could install via below command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then install

```
brew install tor polipo privoxy
```

so tor is installed now, but there further moves to touch.

apped below line in below file (if file dosn't exist create it):

```
/usr/local/etc/polipo/config
```

`below lines:`

```
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

now edit this file:

```
/usr/local/etc/privoxy/config
```

and uncomment below line from it:

```
 forward-socks5t / 127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

**now**

```
brew services start tor

brew services start polipo

brew services start privoxy
```

## For checking if tor is connected or not

use this command:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/tor.log
```

**if not** you have to get a non-obfs-bridge bridge, and it's now deprecated, so you must use `obfs3, scramblesuit, fte, or obfs4`.

to get bridge just email `get transport obfs4` to `bridges@bridges.torproject.org`.

edit `/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc` file and append these below lines to the end of torrc file:

```
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
Bridge `YOUR-OBFS4-BRIDGE`
```

before doing last step [dowload this file](https://download.tuxfamily.org/molaeiorg/dl/obfs4proxy/macosx64/obfs4proxy)  and make it as executable via `chmod +x obfs4proxy` command & put the downloaded file in below directory:

```
/usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
```

now you can restart tor, and it's ready.

```
brew services restart tor
```

[resource](https://molaei.org/tor-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your config - and it's clearly stated in the error message. Edit the config and remove all the lines with the external IP from your error message, so Tor will check it up automatically. You can post your config so I will be able to help you a way better. In your case there's no need for reinstall or another install - *just* fix the config file. If you need further help - just drop me a line!